# How to read bookmarks in PDF using itext at multi level?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using iText-Java to split PDFs at bookmark level.
Does anybody know or have any examples for splitting a PDF at bookmarks that exist at a level 2 or 3?
For ex: I have the bookmarks in the following levels:

Father
|-Son
|-Son
|-Daughter
|-|-Grand son
|-|-Grand daughter

Right now I have below code to read the bookmark which reads the base bookmark(Father). Basically SimpleBookmark.getBookmark(reader) line did all the work.

But I want to read the level 2 and level 3 bookmarks to split the content present between those inner level bookmarks.

```
public static void splitPDFByBookmarks(String pdf, String outputFolder){ 
        try
        { 
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf); 
            //List of bookmarks: each bookmark is a map with values for title, page, etc 
            List<HashMap> bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.getBookmark(reader); 
            for(int i=0; i<bookmarks.size(); i++){ 
                HashMap bm = bookmarks.get(i); 
                HashMap nextBM = i==bookmarks.size()-1 ? null : bookmarks.get(i+1); 
                //In my case I needed to split the title string 
                String title = ((String)bm.get("Title")).split(" ")[2]; 

                log.debug("Titel: " + title); 
                String startPage = ((String)bm.get("Page")).split(" ")[0]; 
                String startPageNextBM = nextBM==null ? "" + (reader.getNumberOfPages() + 1) : ((String)nextBM.get("Page")).split(" ")[0]; 
                log.debug("Page: " + startPage); 
                log.debug("------------------"); 
                extractBookmarkToPDF(reader, Integer.valueOf(startPage), Integer.valueOf(startPageNextBM), title + ".pdf",outputFolder); 
            } 
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        { 
            log.error(e.getMessage()); 
        } 
    } 

    private static void extractBookmarkToPDF(PdfReader reader, int pageFrom, int pageTo, String outputName, String outputFolder){ 
        Document document = new Document(); 
        OutputStream os = null; 

        try{ 
            os = new FileOutputStream(outputFolder + outputName); 

            // Create a writer for the outputstream 
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, os); 
            document.open(); 
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent(); // Holds the PDF data 
            PdfImportedPage page; 

            while(pageFrom < pageTo) { 
                document.newPage(); 
                page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, pageFrom); 
                cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0); 
                pageFrom++; 
            } 

            os.flush(); 
            document.close(); 
            os.close(); 
        }catch(Exception ex){ 
            log.error(ex.getMessage()); 
        }finally { 
            if (document.isOpen()) 
                document.close(); 
            try { 
                if (os != null) 
                    os.close(); 
            } catch (IOException ioe) { 
                log.error(ioe.getMessage()); 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Your help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Just a remark, it seems to me that you are assuming that Bookmarks in PDF will come in the same order as the pages in the document, and this assumption is wrong. You can have a bookmark that points to page 30 and the following bookmark pointing to page 25. You can also have more than one bookmark pointing to the same page, and even to a page in an external PDF document.

Comment: Why are you copying pages using PdfWriter/PdfImportedPage instead of using PdfCopy? That throws away all interactivity! I'm the original developer of iText, and I don't understand your code. Seems like part of it is missing. Can you correct this?

Answer (score 0):

You get an `ArrayList<HashMap>` when you call `SimpleBookmark.getBookmark(reader);` (do the cast if you need it). Try to iterate through that Arraylist and see its structure. If a bookmarks have sons (as you call it), it will contains another list with the same structure.

A recursive method could be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Reference for those who are looking at this using itext7

```
public void walkOutlines(PdfOutline outline, Map<String, PdfObject> names, PdfDocument pdfDocument,List<String>titles,List<Integer>pageNum) { //----------loop traversing all paths
    
for (PdfOutline child : outline.getAllChildren()){
    if(child.getDestination() != null) {
        prepareIndexFile(child,names,pdfDocument,titles,pageNum,list);
    }
  }
}
```

//-----Getting pageNumbers from outlines

```
 public void prepareIndexFile(PdfOutline outline, Map<String, PdfObject> names, PdfDocument pdfDocument,List<String>titles,List<Integer>pageNum) {
    
    String title = outline.getTitle();
    
    PdfDestination pdfDestination = outline.getDestination();
    String pdfStr = ((PdfString)pdfDestination.getPdfObject()).toUnicodeString();
    PdfArray array = (PdfArray) names.get(pdfStr);
    PdfObject pdfObj = array != null ? array.get(0) : null;
    
    Integer pageNumber = pdfDocument.getPageNumber((PdfDictionary)pdfObj);
    
    titles.add(title);
    pageNum.add(pageNumber);
    
    
    if(outline.getAllChildren().size() > 0) {
        
        for (PdfOutline child : outline.getAllChildren()){
            prepareIndexFile(child,names,pdfDocument,titles,pageNum);
        }
        
    }
    
 }

 public boolean splitPdf(String inputFile, final String outputFolder) {

    boolean splitSuccess = true;
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = null;
    try {
        PdfReader pdfReaderNew = new PdfReader(inputFile);
        pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfReaderNew);
        
        final List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Integer> pageNum = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        PdfNameTree destsTree = pdfDoc.getCatalog().getNameTree(PdfName.Dests);
        Map<String, PdfObject> names = destsTree.getNames();//--------------------------------------Core logic for getting names
        PdfOutline root = pdfDoc.getOutlines(false);//--------------------------------------Core logic for getting outlines
        
        walkOutlines(root,names, pdfDoc, titles, pageNum,content);  //------Logic to get bookmarks and pageNumbers
        

        if (titles == null || titles.size()==0) {
            splitSuccess = false;
        }else {                                                             //------Proceed if it has bookmarks
            
            for(int i=0;i<titles.size();i++) {
                 
                 String title = titles.get(i);
                 String startPageNmStr =""+pageNum.get(i);
                 int startPage = Integer.parseInt(startPageNmStr);
                 
                 int endPage = startPage;
                 
                 if(i == titles.size() - 1) {
                     endPage = pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages();
                 }else {
                     int nextPage =  pageNum.get(i+1);
                     if(nextPage > startPage) {
                         endPage = nextPage - 1;
                     }else {
                         endPage = nextPage;
                     }
                 }
                 
                 String outFileName = outputFolder + File.separator + getFileName(title) + ".pdf";
                 PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(outFileName);
                
                 PdfDocument newDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter, new DocumentProperties().setEventCountingMetaInfo(null));
                 pdfDoc.copyPagesTo(startPage, endPage, newDocument);
                 newDocument.close();
                 pdfWriter.close();
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        //---log
    }       
 }
```